# How to change width of Tooltip in Infragistics ig grid

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

On the [offical docs](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2018.2/ui.iggridtooltips#theming:ui-iggrid-tooltip) for Infragistics ig grid, there is nothing mentioned about changing of width.

I have tried:

```
tooltipShowing: function (evt, args) {
  $('#myGrid_tooltips').width(500); // no luck
  $('#myGrid_tooltips').addClass('width-500') // still no luck
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set the width over the element with id `grid_tooltips`. One more thing, all the tooltips has max-width set to equal the width of the column. If you need to show tooltip wider than the column you need to clear max-width. You can do this in tooltipShown event, as tooltipShowing is too early. This code works fine at my side:

```
tooltipShown: function (evt, args) {
    $('#grid_tooltips').css("max-width", "none");
    $('#grid_tooltips').width(550);
}
```